# Which Table in DNN will contain Admin Logs?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I need to export Admin Alerts from DNN's database.

Which table contains this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [dbo].[EventLog]
WHERE 
    LogTypeKey = 'ADMIN_ALERT'

Answer (score 2):

All the logs for DNN are placed in EventLog table, you need to run a direct database query to access eventlog records

Answer (score 1):

It is the table `EventLog`. But keep in mind that since DNN 7 (I think) the logs are automatically removed. In earlier versions the default settings would be to keep all log items, so the table EventLog would sometimes contain millions of records.

So if you want to keep certain logitems for export you need to modify the settings in "Admin > Log Viewer > Edit Log Settings". You'll see a row of log types. You can edit the one you need to change the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its "EventLog" table from DNN database